# How to subtract column values by the first row with awk?

Tags: awk

The input file is lines of "id number1 number2 count", both number1 and number2 are ascendant.

```
Barcode000000 48521 1855 0
Barcode000001 48621 1855 0
Barcode000002 48721 1855 1
Barcode000003 48821 1855 0
Barcode000004 48921 1955 20
Barcode000005 49021 1955 0
```

Now I use `awk -v bin=100 '{print ($2-48521)/bin" "($3-1855)/bin" "$4}'`.

How can I set `48521` and `1855` from the first line of input file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember what they are by saving them in variables and then use those variables to calculate the new fields.  You can detect that you are looking at the first record (line) because the special variable `NR` is 1.  In the code below, I save the numbers into `a` and `b`.

```bash
$ awk -v bin=100 'NR == 1 { a = $2; b = $3 } { $2 = ($2 - a)/bin; $3 = ($3 - b)/bin; print }' file
Barcode000000 0 0 0
Barcode000001 1 0 0
Barcode000002 2 0 1
Barcode000003 3 0 0
Barcode000004 4 1 20
Barcode000005 5 1 0
```

The block preceded by the test `NR == 1` is only ever executed for the first record, while the second block is without condition and executes for all records.

Or, without the first field (which is closer to what the output from your code probably looks like):

```bash
$ awk -v bin=100 'NR == 1 { a = $2; b = $3 } { print ($2 - a)/bin, ($3 - b)/bin, $4 }' file
0 0 0
1 0 0
2 0 1
3 0 0
4 1 20
5 1 0
```

Note that the default output field separator is a single space, so there is no need to insert spaces if you separate the fields of the output record with commas.  The output separator may be changed by setting the value of the special variable `OFS`.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v bin=100 'NR==1{split($0,a)} {for (i=2;i<=3;i++) $i=($i-a[i])/100} 1' file
Barcode000000 0 0 0
Barcode000001 1 0 0
Barcode000002 2 0 1
Barcode000003 3 0 0
Barcode000004 4 1 20
Barcode000005 5 1 0
```

or if you only want to print a small list of specific fields:

```
$ awk -v bin=100 'NR==1{split($0,a)} {for (i=2;i<=3;i++) $i=($i-a[i])/100; print $2, $3, $4}' file
0 0 0
1 0 0
2 0 1
3 0 0
4 1 20
5 1 0
```

or if you have many fields and just don't want to print the first one:

```
$ awk -v bin=100 'NR==1{split($0,a)} {for (i=2;i<=3;i++) $i=($i-a[i])/100; $1=""; sub(OFS,"")} 1' file
0 0 0
1 0 0
2 0 1
3 0 0
4 1 20
5 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`):

```
$ bin=100
$ mlr --nidx step -a from-first -f 2,3 then put '$2 = ${2_from_first} / '$bin' ; $3 = ${3_from_first}/ '$bin'; unset  ${2_from_first}, ${3_from_first}' file
Barcode000000 0 0 0
Barcode000001 1 0 0
Barcode000002 2 0 1
Barcode000003 3 0 0
Barcode000004 4 1 20
Barcode000005 5 1 0
```

Or, without the first field.

```
$ bin=100
$ mlr --nidx step -a from-first -f 2,3 then put '$2 = ${2_from_first} / '$bin' ; $3 = ${3_from_first}/ '$bin'; unset $1, ${2_from_first}, ${3_from_first}' file
0 0 0
1 0 0
2 0 1
3 0 0
4 1 20
5 1 0
```

About `step` subcommand from [Miller Documentation](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-verbs/#step):

> Computes values dependent on earlier/later records, optionally grouped by category.

> from-first Compute differences in field(s) from first record